# Abstract Method Error while UI testing in Compose with MockK

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I'm trying to test WorkoutScreen with the following code block.
I created a function called setView to test ViewState in different situations.

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class WorkoutScreenTest {

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    private val workoutViewModel = mockk<WorkoutViewModel>()

    private val playerManager = mockk<ExoplayerManager>()

    @Before
    fun setup() = runOnUiThread {
        hiltRule.inject()
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, true)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun isCircularProgressDisplayed_whenLoading() = runTest {
        setView(isLoading = true, viewState = WorkoutViewState.Loading)
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("workout_loading_indicator").assertIsDisplayed()
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun isErrorTextDisplayed_whenError() = runTest {
        setView(isLoading = true, viewState = WorkoutViewState.Error("error message"))
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Something went wrong").assertIsDisplayed()
    }

    private fun setView(isLoading: Boolean, viewState: WorkoutViewState) {
        runOnUiThread {
            val loading = MutableStateFlow(isLoading)
            val state = MutableStateFlow(viewState)
            val navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
            coEvery { playerManager.isLoading } answers { loading }
            coEvery { workoutViewModel.state } answers { state }
            coEvery { workoutViewModel.loadExercise(20001) } answers { }
            composeTestRule.setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    WorkoutScreen(viewModel = workoutViewModel, navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code was actually working. But after a while I started getting this error.
`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "boolean kotlin.reflect.KClass.isValue()"`

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?